# Nhibernate translates 1=0

Tags: c#, nhibernate

What causes this 1=0 in Nhibernate

```
SELECT
        this_.LoanId as LoanId89_0_,
        this_.BranchId as BranchId89_0_, 
    FROM

    dbo.Loan this_ 
WHERE
    this_.LoanId in (
        SELECT
            this_0_.LoanId as y0_ 
        FROM
            dbo.MyEntity this_0_ 
        WHERE
            this_0_.MyEntityId = 795
    ) 
    and 1=0 
ORDER BY
    this_.LoanNumber asc;
```

I am trying to retrieve some records and Nhibernate translates it to 1=0 in the AND clause

```
Loan.cs
    public Loan() : base()
        {
            this.Loanid = null; //int32 type
            this.Branchid = null; //int32 type
}
```

This is how a small version of Loan Class looks like. 
It does a WHERE because of subquery. It selects ID because of GetIQueryOverForLoanSearch.It just selects all the columns using Projections and AliasToBean(SearchResult).I just can't understand or figure out where 1=0 comes in?
 There are some more subquery's going on. This is just a very minimal version

```
     var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<MyEntity>().Where(x => x.MyEntityId == entityId).Select(x => x.LoanId);
     var loans = GetIQueryOverForLoanSearch(manager.Session.GetISession(), false).WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(subQuery).OrderBy(x => x.LoanNumber).Asc.List<SearchResult>();

   private static IQueryOver<Loan, Loan> GetIQueryOverForLoanSearch(ISession session, bool setMaxSearchResults = true)
        {
            SearchResult lr = null;
            Loan l = null;

            var queryOver = session.QueryOver(() => l).Select(Projections.Property(() => l.Id).WithAlias(() => lr.LoanId)).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SearchResult>());

            return queryOver;
        }
```

Should I be looking at the DataStructure or criteria?

Comment: How your C# looks like?

Comment: @abatishchev: Hi I just added some C# code. Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: You are going to need to show the "other subqueries" because those might be causing the problem.

Comment: did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the full code? Because I've seen dangling `1 = 0` when empty `Restrictions.Disjunction`s are present, but I don't see any of them there.